Is it true, for every $n,m\in\Bbb{N}$ and some election of signs, that $\sum_{i \in \{m+1,...,m+n\} }\pm \frac{1}{i}=0$?
Motivated by Sum of reciprocal of primes  I have the question of it is true that for every $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$ we can have
$$\sum_{i \in \{m+1,...,m+n\} }\pm \frac{1}{i}=0$$ for some election of the signs.
I know that if $m=0$ or if there is a prime between $m+1$ and $m+n$ it is false, because we can do the trick of consider $p$ the greatest prime in $\{m+1,...,m+n\} $ (so $m+n<2p$) and multiply by $\frac{(m+1)(m+2)\cdots (m+n)}{p}$ in the equation above, so $p$ divides another element in $\{m+1,...,m+n\}$ distinct to $p$ which contradicts the fact that $m+n<2p$

I don't understand the assertion at the start of your posted question.  Take $~m=2,~n=2,~$ and elect to have all terms positive.  Then $$\sum_{i = 3}^4 +\frac{1}{i} \neq 0.$$

@user2661923 My bad, I reeplaced 'any' by 'some' now

Fine, set $~m=2, ~n=2,~$ and demonstrate the satisfying election of signs.

@user2661923 I think I didn't express myself well, but I want to see if when we fix $m$ and $n$ natural numbers there is a choice of signs or not, in the case m=2, and n=2 we both know that we cannot do, but what happen with m, and n in general.

@Sikora I think you better start with one or two examples that actually work (i.e., examples of $m,n$ for which you can find signs with sum of reciprocals $0$).

You multiply by what fraction at the end of the question?

There is no choice of signs to make this sum zero unless $n = 0$, when the sum is empty.
Suppose $\sum_{i=m+1}^{m+n} \frac{\epsilon_i}{i} = 0$ with $\epsilon_i = \pm1$. Let $d$ be the lcm of all $i \in I = \{i : m+1 \leq i \leq m+n\}$. Then $\epsilon_i\frac{d}{i}$ is an integer for all $d$. Claim: All but one of them are even. Then $0 = d\sum_{i=m+1}^{m+n} \frac{\epsilon_i}{i}$ is an odd number. Contradiction!
In order to prove the claim, first note that signs don't change parity, so we can work with $\frac di$ just as well. Let $2^r$ be the highest power of $2$ dividing $d$. Then there is an $i \in I$ such that $i = 2^rt$. Necessarily, $t$ is odd, otherwise $d$ is a multiple of $2^{r+1}$. Suppose there is $i' \in I, i' \neq i$ divided by $2^r$. Choose $i'$ in a way that there are no multiples of $2^r$ between $i$ and $i'$. Write it as $i' = 2^rt'$, again with $t'$ odd. Then $\tilde i = \frac{i+i'}2 = 2^r\frac{t+t'}2$. As $\frac{t+t'}2$ is an integer, we find $\tilde i \in I$, it is divided by $2^r$ and strictly between $i$ and $i'$. A contradiction with the choice of $i'$. This shows that $i$ is the only element of $I$ divided by $2^r$. Now for $i' \neq i$, $\frac d{i'}$ is even, whereas $\frac di$ is odd, proving the claim.
